# What does the word “Canon” (the digicam brand) mean?

Tags: meaning

I know word "canon" because the brand of the digital photography. In my language, Portuguese, this word is considered foreign. When say this word only remember the brand!

But I translated on google translate to find the meaning of this word, in my language, means various words but neither no relates to cameras (http://global.canon/en/)

Thanks

Comment: Look first in an English online dictionary. Google translate is not a dictionary, it doesn't provide the meanings of words, it... erm... translates words, and key expressions into your chosen language. For a learner, your first destination must always be a dictionary.

Comment: I think he wants to know what Canon, as in the brand-name, means. A dictionary may not help much with that.

Comment: @RoaringFish *to find the meaning of this word, in my language,* suggests that the OP believes it has a meaning in English. If he looked in one or more dictionaries he'd have a better understanding. P.S  I refuse to state the obvious answer.

Comment: Does the brand "Chrysler", "Mercedes-Benz", "Toyota" or "Lexus" have anything to do with automobiles? Maybe, maybe not. Why do you think "Canon" has to have a meaning related with a camera? Your question is based on wrong assumption. Does "Nikkon" have anything to do with a camera? Yes, you can Google it.

Comment: Brand names do not have to have any "meaning".  Often (as in "Ford" and "Chrysler") they are the names the people who founded the companies, in other cases ("Kodak" and "Sony") they are complete inventions, chosen only for pronunciation ease and uniqueness.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ~ I was going from the title: "What does the word “Canon” (the digicam brand) mean?"

Comment: @HotLicks the words  *canon* and *cannon* (without capital letters)  are legit though, and their slogan: "You can with Canon.." .or words to that effect, is catchy and uses the modal, *can*, but I am not going to check to see how close or far off the mark I am.

Comment: The company name "Canon" doesn't seem to relate with the word "camera" but the word "canon".

Comment: As the answer by Roaring Fish states, "Canon", as a trade name, is a phonetic transliteration of the name of a Buddhist spiritual figure.  In English it "means" nothing.

Comment: @HotLicks that is exactly what I meant by the "obvious answer", Canon has no meaning in *English*, but Roaring Fish didn't say it. And... since when has EL&U been a translation service, or for that fact, a site that answers Japanese language questions. Why is this question still open after 22 hours?

Answer (score 6):

*The company was originally named Seikikōgaku kenkyūsho (jpn. 精機光学研究所, Precision Optical Industry Co. Ltd.). In 1934 it produced the Kwanon, a prototype for Japan’s first-ever 35 mm camera with a focal plane based shutter.[5] In 1947 the company name was changed to Canon Camera Co., Inc.,[5] shortened to Canon Inc. in 1969. [The name Canon comes from Buddhist bodhisattva Guan Yin (観音, Kannon in Japanese)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_Inc.), previously transliterated as Kuanyin, Kwannon, or Kwanon in English.*

Also, from Canon Museum:

*When Yoshida made his first prototype [camera he named it the Kwanon](http://global.canon/en/c-museum/history/story01.html), after Kannon, the Buddhist goddess of mercy, as he was a Buddhist and an ardent believer in Kannon. The camera’s logo depicted a thousand-arm Kwannon Goddess, and even its lens was named “Kasyapa” which came from Mahakasyapa, a disciple of the Buddha.*

Comment: `The name Canon comes from Buddhist bodhisattva Guan Yin (観音, Kannon in Japanese)` That's not what it says on the [company website](http://web.canon.jp/corporate/logo.html).

Comment: @Earthliŋ - it is what it says on the company website -> http://global.canon/en/c-museum/history/story01.html

Comment: @Roaring Fish They say that the name of the “Kwanon” was changed to “Canon,” which means “standard for judgement or biblical scriptures.” “Canon,” the new trademark for a precision industry company striving for precision as its motto in your link.

Comment: I read it the way that "Kwanon" was the name of the first prototype (after the Buddhist goddess of mercy). They named the company "Canon", after the English word "canon" (as in biblical canon, etc.) fully aware that it didn't mean "Kwanon"; on the website you link it says `"Canon", which means “standard for judgement or biblical scriptures.” “Canon,” the new trademark for a precision industry company striving for precision as its motto, was born at this time.`

Comment: The first part is copied verbatim from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_Inc. (Yes, the piece is clearly in italics and you have included the link, so why not add the name of the source?) The 2nd para names the source and includes the link.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ~ I don't treat people on this site as idiots who can't recognise Wikipedia when they click the link...

Comment: @Earthliŋ ~ the way I read it is that they called their range of cameras 'Kwanon', then anglicised the name as 'Canon' which by good fortune is also a real word. Do you think they would have chosen Canon without the previous Kwanon?

Comment: @RoaringFish `Do you think they would have chosen Canon without the previous Kwanon?` Maybe not, but to me it sounds like they welcomed the change in meaning (from "Buddhist goddess" to "standard for judgement"). This seems to imply that "canon" wasn't ever intended to *mean* "Buddhist goddess", even if the the resemblance was welcome. Anyway, I think I've split enough hairs.

Answer (score 2):

The company name "Canon" doesn't seem to relate with the word "camera" but the word "canon".

The word "canon" has the meanings like canonical books, rule, and standard, so they say on their website that the meanings of "canon" are appropriate for them because they aim to be world standard and rule.

I explain it in detail, the company named their first camera they developed as “Kwanon” , which is the name of one of the most popular Buddhist character. Later the name of the “Kwanon” was changed to “Canon,” which means “standard for judgement or biblical scriptures.” “Canon,” the new trademark for a precision industry company striving for precision as its motto. And then the company changed their company name as Canon.

> **The Birth of Canon** **1933-1936**
>
> Later, the name of the “Kwanon” was changed to “Canon,” which means “standard for judgement or biblical scriptures.” “Canon,” the new trademark for a precision industry company striving for precision as its motto, was born at this time.
>
> [Canon Camera Museum](http://Later,%20the%20name%20of%20the%20%E2%80%9CKwanon%E2%80%9D%20was%20changed%20to%20%E2%80%9CCanon,%E2%80%9D%20which%20means%20%E2%80%9Cstandard%20for%20judgement%20or%20biblical%20scriptures.%E2%80%9D%20%E2%80%9CCanon,%E2%80%9D%20the%20new%20trademark%20for%20a%20precision%20industry%20company%20striving%20for%20precision%20as%20its%20motto,%20was%20born%20at%20this%20time.)

Of course,  the answer by Roaring Fish seem to be one of the reason.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/canon?s=t) explains the meaning of this term

> **canon**
> 3. the body of rules, principles, or standards accepted as axiomatic and universally binding in a field of study or art:

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is explaining the origin of "Canon" as given on the company website.

Comment: At a guess, because the source material is in a foreign language.

Comment: @RoaringFish But source material for a Japanese company is bound to be in Japanese.

Comment: Yes, I am a Japanese and I add links as you say.

Comment: I was suggesting that you copy and paste  the Japanese piece, which you say explains the meaning of the reason why *canon* was chosen, and translate it into English in your answer. We have a few Japanese speakers who are members on EL&U, they could confirm the translation is accurate.

Comment: I already answered the reason. If you want to know that more, please read the links.

Comment: Being called 'Yuuichi Tam' is enough to tell us the poster is Japanese....why does he need to state the obvious in his answer?.

Comment: @Earthliŋ ~ yes... I understand that, and managed to figure out that the poster is Japanese, but regardless of that a Japanese source on an English speaking forum is not very helpful and could trigger down votes. I am not saying I agree with the down votes - just offering a possible reason for them!